# Antd Table Pagination show No Data when moved to second page

Tags: antd

I am using Antd Table component, I have bind data by below code. The first page is load data correctly, but when I moved to the second page, it is showing me 'No Data'. I have debugged code and tried to figure it out issue and found that reached data in render state as well but don't know why not bind it. It's work fond at localhost but when i deployed to server, it couldn't work.
Code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZUmS.png)

Screenshot::
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGaiC.png)

Comment: how do you pass the data? Share the codebase

Comment: Can you provide code in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Which version of ant design you are using, are you using ajax request for populating the second page? There is know bug https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/14723

Answer (score 1):

Its resolved!

I have added current (current:pagination.current) in pagination option in antd table as below

```
<Table
    size={'small'}
                            scroll={{ x: 370 }}
                            rowKey={record => record.template_id}
                            columns={columns}
                            dataSource={roleTemplateData}
                            pagination={{ pageSize: pagination.pageSize, pageSizeOptions: pageSizeOptions, showSizeChanger: true, total: pagination.total, position: position, current:pagination.current }}
                            loading={loading}
                            onChange={this.handleTableChange}
                        />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For people in the future who might have this problem (I also had the problem and solved it):

You probably have the current pageindex and pagesize stored in Redux.

If you have for instance:

- 30 results in total
- a page size of 10
- and you are on page 3

Now you change the page size to 100 (and of course you will only have 1 page) then your redux pageindex is still 3 and you try to access page 3 although only one page exists.

This leads to this error.

Solution:

```js
const pagination = {
  position: ['bottomCenter'],
  showSizeChanger: true,
  showQuickJumper: true,
  onChange: (page) => {
    dispatchFns.setConfig('currentPage', page);
  },
  onShowSizeChange: (_, pPageSize) => {
    dispatchFns.setConfig('currentPage', 1); // this is the necessary line to fix the bug
    dispatchFns.setConfig('pageSize', pPageSize);
  },
  total: itemsToShow.length,
  current: currentPage,
  pageSize,
};

// currentPage comes from Redux
// pageSize comes from Redux
```